# My camera was hidden and I lose the icon. how can I get the icon once again?

Tags: applications

I can't see my camera Icon on my android phone. I check in "application Manage" I see it but the launch button was disable and the disable button too. How can I get one again the Camera's icon so I can access to the camera.

Please may you help me to resolve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it being __hidden__ from app drawer by launcher settings? Please add some details as to what device you have, which Android version, stock or custom ROM, what launcher you have, and any steps you have done that might have caused this. You'll get better answers with a properly asked question. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you go to settings, apps, disabled, can you see the camera app there.

If so, click on it, and click enable.

Comment: I go in the settings, apps, and I see the camera, I see the disable button, but this button is disabled.

Comment: This means the camera app isnt disabled, so have a look in the stock launcher to try and find it